# How to run custom command by pressing a key

Tags: command-line, bash, browser, cmus

I have `cmus` music player installed and I really like it.

I need to run a command by pressing a key, for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> so it will open browser and search a lyrics for currently playing song.

The command might be something like:

`/usr/bin/google-chrome --new-tab http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=[name-of-the-song]`

Is it possible and if so where and how can I define such command ?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for not being clear enough. This has nothing to do with global system keyboard shortcuts (as I know how to made them). Let me explain:

I am running `cmus` music player and within it I am selecting a song to play and play it. Then I want to run an "external command" for this song. By running some key shortcut (while this song is played) I want to run a command that will search lyrics for this song.

Answer (score 2):

To setup a macro, go to **SystemSettings** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**

Click on <kbd>+</kbd> and name your macro & add the command associated with it.

Click again and press your keys to associate it with the command- in your case,

> google-chrome  http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=[name-of-the-song]

Comment: How can I get the `[name-of-the-song]` from `cmus` also how can I run it from within the `cmus` ? Please see my updated question - it's not about global keyboard shortcuts!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the Ubuntu's keyboard key assignment.**

Create the script.  Then assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

**The script**

Example (`findsong.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/google-chrome --new-tab http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=backpack
```

**Assign Key shortcut:**

Type `keyboard` in the Ubuntu Launch Button.

- On the GUI interface click `keyboard` then click the <kbd>+</kbd> key to Add a new Shortcut.
- Type in a Description and a full path to the script; then click apply
- Click on the right column (disabled by default) then hit the key sequence you want to run the script.  For the test I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  This is because `Ctrl+F` is already taken.

Now when you hit the shortcut will run.

Comment: How can I get the `[backpack]` from `cmus` also how can I run it from within the `cmus` ?  Please see my updated question - it's not about global keyboard shortcuts!